# Is it possible to downgrade a "V2" storage account to "V1"?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Some of my Blob storage accounts have been accidentally upgraded to "General Purpose V2". They are now incurring much higher costs than before (over 100 times as much).I want to go back until I have figured out what the best solution would be   in the long term.

I know that the documentation states that the change is permanent, so I have slim hopes for a solution. I did try to change the `kind` via ARM and Azure CLI, like so:

```
az storage account create -g mygroup -n myaccount --kind StorageV2 --sku Standard_LRS
```

It would be awesome if there is a way to downgrade without having to recreate the accounts and copying the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It would be awesome if there is a way to downgrade without having to
>   recreate the accounts and copying the data.

Unfortunately no. Once the account has been upgraded to v2, it can't be downgraded back to v1.

Comment: The only option available today is to delete the storage accounts along with any associated policies and RBAC and create a new storage account with specifications that of v1